# How get variables declared on include page only (not the containing page)?

Tags: php, php-5.3, php-include

I know that I can use `get_defined_vars()` to get the variables declared on a page, but I only want the variables declared on the include page.

I know I can do this:

```
//Get variables of containing page only
$mainPage = get_defined_vars();

//Include new page
include "somepage.php";

//Get variables combined for include and my page
$sothPages = get_defined_vars();

//Find out keys included page
$includeKeys = array_diff_key( $bothPages, $mainPage );

//Now loop through and use only those keys
....
```

But that seems a little messy and slow (especially if I include multiple pages and have to redo this for each one - the `$mainPage` array will keep growing). Is there a better way?

*NOTE: The pages are included dynamically from a list in a properties file, so the code won't know ahead of time which to include*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't have a variable named `$_filename` in the file:

```
function getVarsFromPHPFile($_filename) {
    include $_filename;
    unset($_filename);
    return get_defined_vars();
}

$includeKeys = getVarsFromPHPFile('somepage.php');
```

This should work provided that you aren't declaring the variables as `global`.

Of course, if you change `somepage.php` to return an array (as in `return array(...);`), you could just do `$includeKeys = include 'somepage.php';` instead.

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly. I didn't realize calling it inside a function (which I was going to do) would restrict it only to what was included/declared within that function.